# Highlight comment and remove class when delete button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and currently learning jQuery from codecademy.

I made a simple opinion pull.

**Problem: Besides add comment, i would like to delete the comment when i highlight the comment and press trash button.**

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Boostrap CSs stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--jQuery script-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--Bootsrap js-->
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--CSS stylesheet-->
        <link href="index.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <p class="counter">140</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPost"><div class= "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></div></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDelete"><div class= "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></div></a>
      </div>

      <ul class="posts">
      </ul>
    </div>

        <!--JavaScript script-->
        <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
html,body {
  font-family: courier, sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 520px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.posts {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.posts li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height: 42px;
}
```

index.js

```
var main = function() {
//btnPost
  $('#btnPost').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('.status-box').val('');
    $('.counter').text('140');
    $('#btnPost').addClass('disabled'); 
  });

  $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

    if(charactersLeft < 0) {
      $('#btnPost').addClass('disabled'); 
    }
    else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
      $('#btnPost').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('#btnPost').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  $('#btnPost').addClass('disabled');

 //btnDelete
  $('#btnDelete').click(function(){

  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle to provide something *close* to the desired functionality.  I'm not sure what you mean by "highlight" the comment, but what you are looking for is event delegation. Using jQuery's `.on()` function, you can listen for events on dynamically created elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btnDelete', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/5gL44z6m/2/

And for more info on how the `.on()` function works, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hi @Vince, Many thanks for your help. This is an interesting approach to delete the comment.  Initially i wanna do something like i click the comment 1, then it will indicate the comment 1 box is active. Then it will be removed will i click the trash button.   At the moment the approach you do then i not nessary to make a trash button. How can i achieve that without making the trash button. And the trash sign will directly appear in the comment box?

Comment: @useR I have updated the link to jsFiddle in my answer -- all you would need to do is remove the original delete button.